# how to perform load tests using a java framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, jmeter, load-testing

I'm using Serenity Bdd (based on Selenium WebDriver) framework to test UI of an app. We need some load testing to be done as well.
Do you guys have any suggestions regarding best practices or any tips? I've seen that Jmeter and loadtest4j libraries can be integrated by adding the dependency to the pom.xml file and using imports.
A basic scenario would be to see if an endpoint can handle 100 or 1000 connections at once.
thank you for any input

tried to import Jmeter and loadtest4j but not sure which one will be more useful in the future when complexity increases, using java 17, on a Windows 10 environment with Eclipse

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're testing a web application you should rather go for [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

loadtest4j is a very simple tool which "hammers" the URL while modern web applications are way more "complex" so you will need to take care of:

- [Embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.)
- [Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) of these resources
- Handling [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and other [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- Handling [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests

So JMeter would be way more "future-proof" solution